# почему-то выдается none вместо значений

Tags: python, цвета, rgb

Есть такая програма:

```
from PIL import Image
im1=Image.open('test.jpg') 
im1.convert('RGB')
im1=im1.getcolors()
print(im1)
```

И вместо числовых значений выдается none. Что я делаю не так?
Помогите пж.

Comment: попробуй: colors = Image.Image.getcolors(im1)

Comment: или варианты отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643847/python-how-to-get-a-list-of-color-that-used-in-one-image

Comment: спасибо помогло